# Simple macro help wanted

Tags: autohotkey

I just started using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) yesterday and I am having trouble finding some info. I did search the program's help file, their website and this site and can't seem to locate what i would like to find.

I want to write a simple script that `AutoHotkey` will recognize.

When I press the 'q' key on the keyboard, I would like `AutoHotKey` to do the following:

`Tab key press/release` -> `mouse right click` -> `Tab key press/release`

If anyone with knowledge of `AutoHotKey` workings can help a befuddled n00b out, I'd appreciate it immensely.

Comment: Reviewing the site for AutoHotKey, it seems that this application [has a Macro Recorder](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Macros.htm). This should allow you to perform the desired actions, while the application "captures" what you are doing. This should create the macro for you. Why don't you give this a try, and if it still isn't quite working, post the code that it has created for you here, and someone can better assist you.

Comment: @user2482505 Here is [all the](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#Create) [info](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) you will need

Comment: @user2482505 You don't need any "recorder". You problem can be solved with a couple of the most basic lines of code.

Comment: All of this is covered in the [Beginner's Tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).

Answer (score 1):

As written above tutorials are your friend. You must realize that the letter q will not be usable for writing anymore, unless you define e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> or define this script to ONLY be active when a particular application is active.

In general your script would look like this:

```
q:: ; or ^q:: for Ctrl+q or !q:: for Alt+q or #q:: for Win+q or any combination like ^!#q:: for Ctrl+Alt+Win+q
SendInput, {Tab}
Click, Right
SendInput, {Tab}
Return
```